# ¿Cómo incluir marco de datos en R Markdown?

Tags: r-markdown

Estoy teniendo problemas para incluir un marco de datos en R Markdown y quería pediros ayuda:

He creado un código que me permite hacer un marco de datos en Rstudio, pero cuando lo pongo en un chunk de Rmarkdown no se me imprime el resultado. La verdad que no lo entiendo porque incluso con un código tan básico como el siguiente tampoco me sale el resultado. Agradecería enormemente vuestra colaboración.

```
{r echo=TRUE, eval=TRUE, }

library(dplyr)

A <- c("A","C")  
B <- c("A","B")

C <- data.frame(A,B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tu ejemplo está completo el problema es que estás asignando los datos, no los estás imprimiendo.

Intenta de esta forma y se deberían imprimir los datos:

```r
A <- c("A","C")  
B <- c("A","B")

C <- data.frame(A,B)

C
```